# Android navaigation bar with ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

i just did ListView like this:

All source: [ListView](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/)

Now i want to add navigation bar like iPhone on top of this window:

[image]

I was searching for some source how to do but just kind find. Maybe someone have bookmarked good tutorial how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't have to do this for yourself. Just use a nice lib like [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html) - it supports that NavigationMode for the ActionBar.

Comment: Thanks this looks good library but it's hard for me to make it go. I have created my project and i don't no how i could import that library or even make demo work. I am using eclipse

Comment: Import the ABS-Library as an Android Project, go into it's properties and check it as a library. Afterwards add ABS in your project's properties as a library.

Comment: But i need to use android 3.2 if i want to compile without errors but i want to support from android 2.1 to android 4.x

Comment: That's why u should use ABS - check out his samples. They support Honeycomb and ICS as well as Gingerbread and Froyo.